# (iOS)how to make the button and label working?

Tags: uibutton, uilabel

please take a look my code

```
-(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender{
label1.hidden=NO;
button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM table order by id asc"];
    NSArray *all = [datebase selectData:sql columns:71];
    index = [all count]-1;
    if (index < 0) {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<=index;i++){
            NSArray *row = [all objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *serid = [row objectAtIndex:0];            
            NSString *logtime = [row objectAtIndex:1];                        
            NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?id=%@&logtime=%@",id,ttime];
            NSString *searchTerm = [post stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.theurl.com/sy.php";
            hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:searchTerm];
            NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: hostStr]];
            NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"1"]){
                if (i==index) {
                    NSLog(@"success");
                }
            } 
            else {
                NSLog(@"error");
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

i use the code,and clicked the button, but the label is still hidden, and so to the button1, but if i move the code only left

```
 -(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender{
label1.hidden=NO;
button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  }
```

ok they work, so what's wrong with my code? can anybody help me? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

USE `NSLog(@"bla bla bla")` for trace, like this:

```
-(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"bla bla bla") 
    label1.hidden=NO;
    button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

to check connection with `label1` and `button1` in IB. (outlets)